# How to stop Linux aborting PATH search?

Tags: linux, bash, path, search-path

I have /usr/bin in my PATH, and dot (meaning current directory) later in the PATH. I have a program 'abcxyz' in two directories, /var and /someother.  If I am in a mate-terminal in /var and key in some absurd name, dgxuznk, then bash says: "bash: dgxuznk: command not found" as you would expect.  If I now make a link in /usr/bin called dgxuznk pointing to the program in /someother it runs the program, also as you would expect.  But if I now remove that link, it doesn't say "command not found" any longer, but rather "bash: /usr/bin/dgxuznk: No such file or directory".  It's as if it remembered where it found it before and expects to find it under /usr/bin again.

Even worse, if I now rename the program in /var (where I am) to dgxuznk, and key in "dgxuznk" it still complains "bash: /usr/bin/dgxuznk: No such file or directory" as if it can't get past the /usr/bin in the PATH to see the dot and look in the current directory to find the program.

Is this only in Fedora 19?  How can I program it to get past the /usr/bin in the search path and find the current directory dot?

(Hint: if you want to reproduce this error - don't let it find the program in the current directory until after it's found it in /usr/bin.)

Comment: Don't put `.` in `$PATH`. It is a security issue waiting to happen.

Answer (score 6):

`bash` maintains an in-memory hash of where programs are found so that it doesn't have to go through the full path lookup every time a command is run. Each `bash` session maintains its own hash, but you can manipulate it with the built-in `hash` command. To see what is in the hash, just run it with no arguments. To clear it, use `hash -r`. In your case, you just want to remove `dgxuznk` with `hash -d gdxuznk`.

(You might ask why `bash` doesn't just remove a entry from the hash if the location isn't found. There might be a good reason for reporting an error instead of falling back to path lookup, or it might be a bug or an area to improve.)

Comment: Thank you very much chepner.  I didn't know 'hash' existed.  But it's tantamount to mutiny!  There's NO WAY that it should give up on executing a program if it's in the PATH list.  And also it is incorrect operation in that the user may specially set up the ORDER of the directories in PATH to pick the right one.  This hash thing would defeat that.  And also come up and say it couldn't find a program when it's right there in the list!!  I'm flabbergasted!  Is there any way to turn it off for good?

Comment: I don't think you can disable it, but you can clear it with `hash -r` each time you change `PATH`. However, `PATH` isn't something you would ordinarily need to change often during a `bash` session.